# Thread Pools - restricting calls to certain methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

Is there a way to tell the thread pool mananger to only have *x* number of threads invoking a specific method or group of methods?

I have an application where I use thread pool worker threads all over the place, and it works swimmingly; one of the tasks I consign to the worker threads is a web service call, however, and it will reject more than 5 concurrent requests.  I don't want to limit the thread pool to 5 threads, because many other things use the threads and can handle a great many more.

Is there a way to "compartmentalize" a thread pool to say "you will have a maximum of *x* threads active doing this particular thing at any point in time, but the rest of you threads can go do other stuff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another threadpool and SetMaxThreads(5) - it's the easiest way.

OK, you can't do it with Threadpool class.

Just so I'm not downvoted:

```
public abstract class Task {
    public EventHandler FonComplete;
    public ThreadPool myPool;
    protected int param;
    public Exception error;
    public Task(int inParam, EventHandler OnDone) { param = inParam; FonComplete = OnDone; }
    public abstract void run();
};


public class PoolThread{
private
    BlockingCollection<Task> FinQueue;
public
    PoolThread(BlockingCollection<Task> inQueue)
    {
       FinQueue=inQueue; 
    }
    Task inMess;
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            inMess=FinQueue.Take();
            if(inMess==null) return;
            try
            {
                inMess.run();
                inMess.error = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                inMess.error = e;
            }
            inMess.FonComplete(inMess, null);
        }
    }
};

public class ThreadPool {
    int FthreadCount;
    BlockingCollection<Task> queue;
    void startThread(){
            PoolThread thisPoolThread=new PoolThread(queue);
            Thread thisThread=new Thread(new ThreadStart(thisPoolThread.run));
            thisThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            thisThread.IsBackground = true;
            thisThread.Start();
    }
    void SetThreadCount(int newCount){
        while(FthreadCount<newCount){startThread();};
        while(FthreadCount>newCount){
            queue.Add(default(Task));
            FthreadCount--;
        };
    }
    public ThreadPool(int initThreads){
        queue=new BlockingCollection<Task>();
        for(FthreadCount=0;FthreadCount<initThreads;FthreadCount++) startThread();
    }
    public int threadCount{
        get{return FthreadCount;}
        set
        {
            while (FthreadCount < value) {
                startThread();
                FthreadCount++;
            };
            while (FthreadCount > value)
            {
                queue.Add(default(Task));
                FthreadCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void submit(Task task){
        task.myPool=this;
        queue.Add(task);
    }
};

}
```

It's not like the 'real' System.Threading.Threadpool, but  it is a threadpool with a fixed number of threads

Comment: I may be missing something, but there does not seem to be a way to do this.

Comment: Wot?  I;m sure I've read that somewhere?  How come both Servy and myself both immediately thought of the same answer?

Comment: @MartinJames until you show how you create another ThreadPool, this is just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, at least I'm trying...  :((

Comment: This seems to be the proper way to go; a bit frustrating that it's necessary, but oh well.

Comment: I agree.  I see no convincing argument for making the built-in Threadpool anything but a 'normal' class that can be instantiated with new() in the usual way.

Answer (score 4):

Use a Semaphore to limit access to the scarce resource to max. 5.

A Semaphore can be configured to only allow concurrent access for N threads. You need to configure the Semaphore with N=5 and have all threads wait on it before calling the webservice.

Comment: can you elucidate please?  I don't follow.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work in this case.  Instead of being available to work on other tasks, the extra pool threads will just get blocked on the semaphore.

Comment: Yes, they will be blocked but the thread pool will just spawn new threads to replace them. The thread pool can detect blocking.

Comment: Wow i have never heard of this before.  I will try to wrap my brain around it.

Comment: I'm not so sure that blocking [no. of submitted web tasks -5] threads is a good idea, but I've no reason to think it wouldn't work.  Certainly worth a test as so simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one thread pool.  Have thread pool A with a max of 5 threads for requests to your webservice, and thread pool B with a much higher max for everything else.

Comment: How does one create a new, separate ThreadPool?  It does not seem to have a constructor.

Comment: Hmm...too much time in the Java world for me it seems.  I guess you'd need to make your own threadpool to do that, and that's probably not worth it here.

Comment: That's my first thought too :((  Second thought, if you can't make another threadpool instance - why?  It's a class, so why can't I make one?  It's just daft to put that restriction on.

Comment: I guess the decision was made to prevent subsystems and libraries to open their own pools and oversubscribe the CPU by a multiple. This decision is questionable, but reasonable.

Comment: It's not justifiable, IMHO.  It's sucking the flexibility out of the language.  Independent subsystems are just.... normal!  F.. M$...

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `Task` class instead of using the `ThreadPool` directly. Spin up a parent task that loops through each of your work items and spins up a child task. The parent task will use a semaphore to limit the number of concurrent child tasks.

This is a lot better than having your child task wait on the semaphore because now we only have one pooled thread waiting on the semaphore as opposed to many.

```
var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () =>
  {
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5);
    foreach (var workitem in YourWorkItems)
    {
      var capture = workitem;
      semaphore.Wait();
      Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
        {
          try
          {
            CallWebService(capture);
          }
          finally
          {
            semaphore.Release();
          }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    }
  }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

// Optionally wait for the parent to complete here.
// Because our child tasks are attached this will wait until everything is done.
parent.Wait();
```